# Beautiful soup arabic encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, character-encoding

I am using Beautiful Soup to scrape some text but it's outputing strange characters.

My Python 2.7 code:

```
source = requests.get('https://alwafd.news/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%82-%D8%A5%D9%84%D9%89-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
for article in soup.find_all('div' , class_='item'):
    headline = article.h3.text.encode('utf8')
```

Here is my output:

```
Ø´ÙØ±Ù Ø§ÙØ¬ÙØ¯Ù : Ø³ÙØ¹ÙØ± Ø³ÙÙØ§Ø¡ Ø±ØºÙ Ø£ÙÙ Ø§ÙØ­Ø§ÙØ¯ÙÙ
```

Here is the expected output

```
خطة النواب توافق على رفع ضريبة إجمالى عمليات بيع الأوراق المالية
```

I'm not sure how to encode properly to get the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `BeautifulSoup` determine the encoding.  In this case, there's no `charset` specified in the response headers, so `BeautifulSoup` will do a better job at decoding than `requests`.

```
>>> source = requests.get('https://alwafd.news/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%82-%D8%A5%D9%84%D9%89-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'lxml')
>>> for article in soup.find_all('div' , class_='item'):
...     print article.h3.text
... 
خطة النواب توافق على تعديلات قانون ضريبة الدخل لدعم شركات قطاع الأعمال
خطة النواب توافق على رفع ضريبة إجمالى عمليات بيع الأوراق المالية
مطالبات بمحاسبة المجتمع الدولي تركيا على انتهاكاتها
خطة البرلمان توافق على استمرار إيقاف العمل بضريبة الأطيان الزراعية لمدة عامين
اقتصادية النواب توافق على تعديل قانون شركات قطاع الأعمال العام
شكرى الجندى يتقدم ببيان عاجل لتثبيت متضرري التربية والتعليم بكفر الشيخ
إفريقية البرلمان تضامن مع دول شرق القارة اجتاحتها الفيضانات
إنفوجراف.. أهم 10 تصريحات أطلقها رئيس مجلس النواب منذ أزمة كورونا
شكرى الجندى يطالب النائب العام بالتحقيق مع وزير الثقافة السابق
تجاهل مطالب المرشديين السياحيين على طاولة البرلمان
فرج عامر : تسليط CNN للأضواء على قناة السويس أكبر دعاية لجذب الاستثمارات العالمية للمنطقة
خطة النواب تكشف تراجع إيرادات هيئة البريد
طارق شوقي : ندرس سيناريوهات المنظومة التعليمية في العام الدارسي الجديد
شوقي: طلاب أولى وثانية ثانوي محظوظين لأن معهم أجهزة تابلت
د.محمد خليفه يطالب بإدراج مشاكل مصانع المحلة على جدول أعمال مجلس الوزراء
رئيس أفريقية النواب يعترض علي هجوم نائبة كويتية علي وزيرة الهجرة
شكرى الجندى : سنعمر سيناء رغم أنف الحاقدين
معيط: أزمة كورونا وضعت وزارة المالية أمام خيارين تجاه الموازنة
```